# When does an operation really occur when it is a parameter in a function

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function that looks like this:

```
var meowLikeACat = function(howoften) { 
    setInterval(function() { 
        alert("meow"); 
    },howoften*1000) 
}
```

and let's say that i'm calling it like this:

```
var howOften_local = 3;
meowLikeACat(howOften_local+1);
```

At what point does that `+1` operation actually occur?

And would it be possible to 'intercept' the data that was being passed before the function ran?

Comment: What do you think is happening? Some simple console.log statements can probably answer it.

Comment: @epascarello how is that relevant?

Comment: @Xander well I wrote out 3 other ways that i thought it *could* happen

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your first two dot, points. The parameters are passed when the function is called.

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree; I said as much in my answer.

Comment: I was wondering wether or not it would be possible to 'intercept' the data that was being passed before the function ran. @nnnnnn

Comment: Maybe you should describe your ultimate problem or goal. You can "intercept" it by passing it through another function that returns the same value. `meowLikeACat(other_func(howOften_local+1));` ... `function other_func(x) { console.log(x); return x; }`

Comment: @thesystem well i mean if it's possible, then I would love to bind another function to listen on anothers' call and intercept the data being passed for validation/etc ( though there is already a million ways to do this i was curious as to wether this was even possible )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At what point does that `+1` operation actually occur?

All parameters are evaluated, left-to-right, immediately before being passed to the function.

> #### [11.2.3 Function Calls](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3)
>
> The production *CallExpression* : *MemberExpression* *Arguments* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *MemberExpression*.
> 2. Let *func* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*ref*).
> 3. Let *argList* be the result of evaluating *Arguments*, producing an internal list of argument values ([see 11.2.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.4)).
> 4. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*func*) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 5. If [IsCallable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.11)(*func*) is **false**, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 6. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*ref*) is [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7), then
>      a. If [IsPropertyReference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)(*ref*) is true, then
>             i. Let *thisValue* be GetBase(*ref*).
>      b. Else, the base of *ref* is an [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1)
>              i. Let *thisValue* be the result of calling the ImplicitThisValue concrete method of [GetBase](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)(*ref*).
> 7. Else, [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*ref*) is not [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7).
>      a. Let *thisValue* be **undefined**.
> 8. Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method on *func*, providing *thisValue* as the **this** value and providing the list *argList* as the argument values.
>
> #### [11.2.4 Argument Lists](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.4)
>
> The evaluation of an argument list produces a List of values (see 8.8).
>
> The production *Arguments* : `( )` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return an empty List.
>
> The production *Arguments* : `(` *ArgumentList* `)` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return the result of evaluating *ArgumentList*.
>
> The production *ArgumentList* : *AssignmentExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 2. Let *arg* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*ref*)
> 3. Return a [List](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.8) whose sole item is *arg*.
>
> The production *ArgumentList* : *ArgumentList* , *AssignmentExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *precedingArgs* be the result of evaluating *ArgumentList*.
> 2. Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 3. Let *arg* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*ref*).
> 4. Return a [List](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.8) whose length is one greater than the length of *precedingArgs* and whose items are the items of *precedingArgs*, in order, followed at the end by *arg* which is the last item of the new list.

---

> And would there be any way of forcing the operation to occur in any of the above?

The first two are the same. I don't see how you could distinguish between the time when a function is called and the time when a parameter is passed to the function.

You could accomplish the third by passing a function instead:

```
function meowLikeACat(howoften) {
    setInterval(function() { 
        alert("meow"); 
    }, howoften()*1000) 
}

var howOften_local = 3;
meowLikeACat(function () {
    return howOften_local+1;
});
```

---

> And would it be possible to 'intercept' the data that was being passed before the function ran?

This is simple, if your code assumes cooperation rather than hostility:

```
function meowLikeACat(howoften) { 
    setInterval(function() { 
        alert("meow"); 
    }, howoften*1000) 
}

function intercept(thisArg, original, before) {
    return function() {
        // could manipulate arguments here,
        // or pass something completely different to original
        before.apply(thisArg, arguments);
        original.apply(thisArg, arguments);
    };
}

function doBefore() {
    console.log('before', arguments);
}

var meowLikeACatIntercepted = intercept(null, meowLikeACat, doBefore);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/e4AY6

Comment: I kind of mis-worded my last question initially, there's an edit though :)

Comment: wow, well this was ridiculously well explained, thanks a tonne coolcat!

Answer (score 1):

It happens on the spot.

```
var howOften_local = 3;
meowLikeACat(howOften_local+1);
```

This code is basically doing it like:

```
meowLikeACat(4);
```